# Related entity not populating

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an entity which looks something like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int OwnerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(OwnerId))]
    public virtual User Owner { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(CategoryId))]
    public virtual Lookup Category { get; set; }
}
```

I am facing a problem whereby only the `Owner` navigation property is being populated, but not my `Category` navigation property and I am not sure why.

I am adding an entity via a generic repository like this:

```
public virtual T Add(T entity)
{
    return DbContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
}
```

And I am attempting to pull out the category name like this:

```
public Item CreateItem(Item item)
{
    var createdItem = ItemListRepository.Add(item);
    UnitOfWork.Commit();
    //DataContext.Items.Include(x => x.Category).First(x => x.Id == createdItem.Id);
    AuditService.AddUserActionAudit<Item>(
            AuditAction.ItemCreation, 
            $"Added new {createdItem.Category?.Name ?? "item"}: {item.Description}", 
            item.Id);
    return createdItem;
}
```

The category will only be populated whenever I have included the commented out line of code to retrieve the entity but also explicitly requesting the related Category entity. Why do I have to do this for my Category entity but not my Lookup entity? What might be different here that would be cause for a difference in behaviour?

I can't see any notable differences between my Lookup (Category) and User entity - I can post them here if you think it's worth looking at.

Comment: Probably because your DbContext already holds a reference to the other entity, for example because you load it for another operation. We can't really say anything about this without a [mcve].